# Oozie coordinator input

Tags: input, time, oozie

I use Oozie coordinator to run a Java program every day. The input parameter of Java program is time, just like 20150201. I don't know how to get the time as input, so what should I do to set the configuration of Oozie? Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your oozie workflow keep a shell script action which will execute everyday and emits the time you want in that fashion to a variable. Capture the output of that variable and pass that to Java action.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html

There are examples given here for shell actions and capture output.

In shell script you could use something like this date command `date +%Y%m%d` to emit the year month and date.

Hope it helps.